# Jenkins build ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET Core 1.0) Unable to resolve dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, jenkins, msbuild, asp.net-core

I'm trying to set up my Jenkins server to be able to build ASP.NET 5 RC1 (soon to be ASP.NET Core 1.0) projects. However, I'm getting the following error when the build tries to run:

```
C:\Users\{User}\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\dnx.exe --appbase "D:\ASPCore\KBA\KBA.PublicWeb.Core" "C:\Users\{User}\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\lib\Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling\Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.dll" pack "D:\ASPCore\KBA\KBA.PublicWeb.Core" --configuration Debug --out "..\artifacts\bin\KBA.PublicWeb.Core"
  Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231
  Building KBA.PublicWeb.Core for DNX,Version=v4.5.1
    Using Project dependency KBA.PublicWeb.Core 1.0.0
      Source: D:\ASPCore\KBA\KBA.PublicWeb.Core\project.json
    Unable to resolve dependency EntityFramework.Commands 7.0.0-rc1-final
    Unable to resolve dependency EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer 7.0.0-rc1-final
    Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies 1.0.0-rc1-final
    Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity 7.0.0-rc1-final
    ... //etc
```

I get the same results if I remote into the server and try to run msbuild myself. How can I get msbuild to automatically restore these packages to run my build?

I know I have RC1 installed, because I was getting a different error before I installed that. Now it's trying to build, just can't find dependencies.